# Can't get Chromecast to connect to my wifi, I have an Actiontec Q1000

Tags: wireless-networking, android, chromecast

I put the Chromecast into my HDMI tv and downloaded the app to my Android phone and my Android Tablet. My laptop which is Windows Vista says it is not supported.  When I try to connect to my wifi from my android devices it says it can't find Chromecast. I have researched and read that my upnp needs to be enabled on my Qwest (now Centurylink) Actiontec Q1000 modem and called century link to have them enable it, since I was not able to on my end. They said that all their modems come with upnp already enabled.  So now I am stuck, How do I get my Chromecast to connect to my wifi???

Did I maybe get a bad device??

Answer (score 1):

I have a Q1000 modem also and was having trouble getting Chromecast to connect to the Internet.  Solved problem by opening some Service Ports for UDP traffic. A few Q1000 router settings need to be changed.

Enter the address 192.168.0.1 in a browser window. Then click on "Advanced Setup" followed by clicking on Firewall listed under Security.  In table #4, "Set the Firewall table below. Services checked are allowed.", check the Traffic In and Traffic Out boxes for DirectX, Direct TV STB 1, Direct TV STB 2, and Direct TV STB 3. Note that the ports are for Multimedia Control and Services. After checking the boxes scroll to bottom of page and click "Apply."

After the router applied the changes, my Chromecast device started working.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with my Dsl Asus router, I tried all of the suggestions. The thing that seemed to work in the end was turning of qos.

Answer (score 1):

I just got my chrome cast working again after 2 days of headaches. It had been working over for over 1 year, then It stopped connecting. i even bought another chromecast with no luck. I tried many solutions on other forums with no luck, like changing encryptions, open network, MAC numbers etc etc.

The i got a friend to manually Reset my router and set it up from scratch again, with a new name and password. Hard reset for the chrome cast again and the two came together in a flash. straight through the configuration without a hitch.

hope this helps any one else

Answer (score 0):

I have an Actiontec C1000 gateway. Couldnt connect Chromecast, Called Century they were (as usual) useless. Then called Actiontec, the support gal bluntly said that none of their products support Chromecast. 
So this is how I made it work.
type the url 192.168.0.1 in your web browser 
open the router page then go to Advanced settings
Under Security --> Choose IPv6 Firewall
Under Table #3 Select 'Allow' for Traffic In
Scroll down and hit Apply

and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

For a Linksys WRT150N router, you have to uncheck "Filter Anonymous Internet Requests" under Security, Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution!

I worked for a full day changing settings on my Q1000, with no success. I have my Q1000, my Samsung Galaxy 3 (SG3) and my Chromecast.

Finally, I downloaded the Chromecast App to my PC, rather than using my SG3. Just go to https://cast.google.com/chromecast/setup from your PC, download the app, using your Chrome Browser, and hopefully you will get the same results that I did.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have a century link PK5001Z that could not connect to my Chromecast. I went to advanced settings, IPv6 Firewall. Select "Allow" on "Traffic In". It allowed me to stream media through the Chromecast but not adjust the background. Will function well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For Linksys e3000, disable the Frame Burst settings(next to AP isolation) worked fine for now.
Earlier it worked fine after disabling AP isolation, but again stopped after some time.
And after doing trial and error many times, finally disabling Frame Burst option worked. And by this time, I have started hating the chromecast....Roku and others work so seamlessely ...but this chromecast is pain in the a..